# Puppeteer issue on NextJS 13: TypeError: oe is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js, puppeteer

I had my project, it was working perfectly, had a function inside app/api/getItem/route.ts which was working great and using import puppeteer from 'puppeteer', but I accidentally ran npm uninstall puppeteer while uninstalling unused packages, but reinstalled it as soon as I realized it. My route doesn't work now, and I keep getting the following error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: oe is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
oe
node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs (1:61375)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (1725:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/node_modules/yargs/yargs.mjs (5:74)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/node_modules/yargs/yargs.mjs
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (2044:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/CLI.js (10:69)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/CLI.js
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (1736:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/main.js (26:65)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/main.js
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (1890:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js (7:77)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (2924:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/node.js (11:76)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/node.js
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (2990:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/puppeteer-core.js (140:71)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/puppeteer-core.js
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (3001:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/puppeteer.js (138:99)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/puppeteer.js
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (3133:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/getItem/route.ts (5:67)
(sc_server)/./app/api/getItem/route.ts
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (344:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js (13:147)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2FgetItem%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2FgetItem%2Froute.ts&appDir=%2FUsers%2Fsebastianrubina%2FDocuments%2Fwebdev%2Fprojects%2Faffiliate-links%2Fapp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=%2FUsers%2Fsebastianrubina%2FDocuments%2Fwebdev%2Fprojects%2Faffiliate-links&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&assetPrefix=!
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (333:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:43)
__webpack_exec__
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (3187:39)
<unknown>
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (3188:28)
Object.<anonymous>
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/.next/server/app/api/getItem/route.js (3191:3)
Module._compile
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (1159:14)
Module._extensions..js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (1213:10)
Module.load
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (1037:32)
Module._load
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (878:12)
Module.require
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader (1061:19)
require
node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers (103:18)
Object.requirePage
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js (88:12)
<unknown>
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js (49:73)
async Object.loadComponentsImpl [as loadComponents]
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js (49:26)
async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl
file:///Users/sebastianrubina/Documents/webdev/projects/affiliate-links/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js (600:36)
```

This is my api route:

```js
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
// import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

export async function POST(request: Request, response: NextApiResponse) {
  // const body = request.body;
  const req = await request.json();
  const url = req.amazonUrl;
  console.log("url", url);

  // const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  //   headless: true,
  //   defaultViewport: null,
  // });
  // const page = await browser.newPage();
  // await page.goto(url, {
  //   waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  // });

  // const item = await page.evaluate(() => {
  //   const title = document.querySelector("#productTitle")?.innerHTML.trim();

  //   const imageContainer = document.querySelector(".imgTagWrapper");
  //   const imageUrl = imageContainer?.querySelector("img")?.src;
  //   const rating = document.querySelector(".a-icon-alt")?.textContent?.trim();
  //   let price = document
  //     .querySelector("#sns-base-price")
  //     ?.textContent?.trim()
  //     .slice(1)
  //     .replace(",", "");
  //   if (!price) {
  //     price = document
  //       .querySelector(".a-price-whole")
  //       ?.textContent?.trim()
  //       .replace(",", "");
  //   }
  //   console.log("ITEM: " + item);
  //   return { title, price, imageUrl, rating };
  // });

  // return new Response(JSON.stringify(item));

  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({
      title: "hi",
      price: 10,
      imageUrl: "https://www.google.com",
      rating: 3,
    })
  );
}
```

I commented everything related to puppeteer and now the function works, why could this be?

I have tried running with --turbo, I tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and rerunning npm install, but to no success.

This is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "affiliate-links",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.4",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.7",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "eslint": "8.37.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "firebase": "^9.19.1",
    "iframe-resizer": "^4.3.6",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "puppeteer": "^19.8.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.3",
    "utf-8-validate": "^6.0.3",
    "ws": "^8.13.0",
    "yargs": "^17.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

My npm version is 8.19.2 and my node version is 18.12.1.

The issue happens as soon as I uncomment the `const browser = await puppeteer.launch...` line.

Comment: Can you post your relevant package.json so we have your Puppeteer version? Node version? I don't really see a complete/sensible stack trace here--is it related to the import or some line of Puppeteer code (which one)? Thanks. [Cross post for future reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/12esq6i/issue_with_nextjs_and_puppeteer/)

Comment: Hi @ggorlen and thanks for your answer! I have updated the post with the `package.json` and some more inforation. It is extremely weird as it was working properly, and I didn't have anything between the time when I uninstalled `puppeteer` accidentally and reinstalled it, so I'm not sure what could have gotten messed up.

Comment: Thanks, these details are helpful. I'm not sure what's going on, but does Puppeteer not work when you remove next.js from the picture? This helps minimize the problem. I suggest two lines in a script: just import and launch Puppeteer. If that fails, then it's probably some bad Puppeteer installation or system misconfiguration of some sort. If it works, then it seems like it's related to the build process.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have the same exact issue...

Comment: Got exactly the same error but with a fresh Nextjs app. All I did was adding puppeteer a route with a GET request. Within that GET request all I have is `const browser = await puppeteer.launch()`. next `13.4.0` and puppeteer `20.1.0`. Any luck?

Comment: Exact same issue here, puppeteer 20.1.0, Next13.